# Issue with rendering a4 size page in mobile screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, editor

I'm developing an editor in react js which contain a4 size editable pages working good in laptops but in case of mobile screens getting horizontal screen not able to detect how to resolve that.

**html**

```
    <div>
       <div class="page" />
    </div>
```

**css**

```
.page {
  width: 21cm;
  height: 29.7cm;
  padding: 1cm;
  margin: 0.5cm auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 }

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}

@media print {
  .page {
    margin: 0;
    border: initial;
    border-radius: initial;
    width: initial;
    min-height: initial;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Sok.png)
    box-shadow: initial;
    background: initial;
    page-break-after: always;
  }
```

}

```
scale: 0.45;
transform-origin: top left;
```

added the above style to reduce page scale to render in mobile but getting extra blank space around the page.

expecting to render horizontally in single screen without extra space and scroll.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7otTa.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can correct this by doing some changes in your CSS

```
.page{
  width:100vw;
  height: 29.7cm;
  padding: 1cm;
  margin: 0.5cm auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```